# Is there an Android app/widget to *temporarily* turn on mobile data?

Tags: mobile-data

Is anyone aware of an Android app or widget to temporarily turn on mobile data, then disable it again after a set period of time?

I have a bad habit of turning on my phone's data for a specific purpose, but then forgetting to turn it back off.  As a result, non-critical apps (like a current-weather widget -- I don't really care if it updates current info only if I'm wifi-connected) continue to use data.

I'd like to be able to enable data and then disable it automatically 15 minutes or so later, when I invariably forget to turn it off myself.

Browsing Google Play turns up nothing likely, nor does a Google web search.  The closest I could find was an app that turns mobile data on and off at specific times, which provides a proof of concept that this can be done, but still is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Something like Tasker might be able to tell when data is turned on, and you could script it to turn it off after that set time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Tasker a few days ago, and it turns out this is pretty straightforward once I got past the learning curve and oriented to how it does things.

I set up a task with three subtasks (plus a couple test alerts to give me audible progress): (a) Mobile Data: Set On; (b) Wait 10 minutes; (c) Mobile Data: Set Off. Then I added a shortcut to the task.

Once I get a little bit better at Tasker, I'll probably try enhancing it to put up a warning dialog, allowing me to extend another 10 minutes or, if not responded to, continuing with the MD disable.  But I've got what I need now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are  you thinking of something like [BatteryFu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tobykurien.batteryfu)?

Its description on Google Play is

> Description
>
> BatteryFu (pronounced Battery-Foo, like in Kung-Fu) extends battery life (and lowers data usage) by changing always-on mobile/wifi data to periodic sync (meaning it disables your mobile data and/or Wifi, then checks your accounts every X minutes). This also provides a way to manage your data usage.
>
> BatteryFu is also great for tablet use to keep accounts sync'd even when the tablet is in sleep/standby. Normally accounts won't sync due to WiFi going to sleep (see "WiFi sleep policy").
>
> There are lots of other battery savers on the market, but this one has been around since 2010, and has no ads or spyware (see permissions). BatteryFu is open source software.
>
> Features:
>
> - Lean and fast (see download size!)
> - Work for all networks (CDMA/GSM) from Gingerbread up
> - Notification icon: lets you switch modes even while inside another app.
> - Data while screen is on, with screen off delay
> - Data while charger is plugged in
> - Pre-defined modes: Travel mode, Online mode, Offline mode, Night mode, etc.
> - BatteryMinder shows battery stats, like usage during screen off, kernel wakelocks, etc.
> - 3rd party app support (using intents) so that you can control BatteryFu from your own app.
> - Open source

Comment: Thank you it never occurred to me to look for a battery saver that would disable mobile data as a side effect.  That probably would have worked, but I tried Tasker and have that working now.

Comment: FYI, it says that in Android 5 or higher it needs Root access to control Mobile Data :(